# Sending messages in twitter using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter

I am trying to integrate a feature in my react app in which we can send message to our followers the invitation to our app. I searched so many resources but couldnt find.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

1. Use any kind of backend (Python, Ruby, et.c.) and kick [Twitter official API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update.html) for this
2. Use [tweet button](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/tweet-button/overview) which is embed to your react code